# Only query "Where" if there is a value in Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, class, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a search query that needs to be done. However, a search doesn't always have all values set, like in this case.

```
$aEvents = DB::table('events')
->where('client_id', '=', $client_id);
```

The question is, how can I make this where statement depend on the value of $client_id. So if the value is empty I don't want the Where statement to occur.

Also, I do not want to write several complete queries with if statements in PHP. To many variables. Ideally I'd like something like this:

```
$aEvents = DB::table('events')
->(($client_id != "") ? where('client_id', '=', $client_id) : "");
```

Using eloquent is (really!) nice and save, but I'm not yet up to speed with if statements in std Class objects I guess. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
$query = DB::table('events');
if(!empty($client_id)) {
    $query->where('client_id', $client_id);
}
$aEvents = $query->get(); // Call this at last to get the result
```

If you are passing `client_id` to the server via a `form/query string(user input)` then you may try something like this:

```
if($client_id = Input::get('client_id')) {
     $query->where('client_id', $client_id);
}
```

**Update:** For pagination try this:

$aEvents = $query->paginate(10); // For 10 per page

So you may call `links()` method in your view if you pass it like this:

```
return View::make('viewName')->with('aEvents', $aEvents);
```

In the view for pagination links:

```
$aEvents->links()
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting, but unfortunatally this doesn't work. it throws an exception as soon as I try to split the query. "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::links()"

Comment: You are calling `links()`, that's why `"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::links()"`.

Comment: If you want to pagination links then try `$aEvents = $query->paginate(10); `, `10` could be any number (items per page).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use query scopes in the model for this purpose. Scopes allow you to easily re-use query logic in your models. In the model `Event`, you can add the following query scope:

```
public function scopeClientID($query, $client_id)
{
    if ($client_id != '') {
        return $query->where('client_id', '=', $client_id);
    } else {
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Then from your controller or wherever you're calling it from, you can do the following:

```
$aEvents = Event::clientID($client_id);
```

If you want to get all the results, then you can do:

```
$aEvents = Event::clientID($client_id)->get();
```

Or if you want pagination, you can do:

```
$aEvents = Event::clientID($client_id)->paginate();
```

You can also chain it with other methods like you'd do in a eloquent query.

You can read more about model query scopes at http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes